# TransactionScope priority (get rid of deadlock situation)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, deadlock, transactionscope

I have process A that runs every 5 minutes and needs to write something in table "EventLog". This works all day long but at night there is another process B starting that needs to delete a lot of old data from this table. The table has millions of rows (blobs included) and many related tables (deletion by cascade) so process B runs up to ~45 minutes. While process B is running I get a lot of deadlock warnings for process A and I want to get rid of these.

The easy option would be "Don't run process A when process B is running" but there must be a better approach. I am using EntityFramework 6 and TransactionScope in both processes. I didn't find out how to set priority or something like that on my processes. Is this possible?

**EDIT:**
I forgot to say that I am already using one delete transaction per record, not one transaction for all records. Inside loop I create new DBContext and TransactionScope, so each record has its own transaction. My problem is that deleting a record still takes some time because of the related BLOBs and data in other related tables (lets say about 5 sec. per row). I still get deadlock situations when deleting process (B) crosses with inserting process (A).

Comment: If they all have certain times, can you align them? Like if A takes 1 min to perform, and starts at 20:00, you can start B at 20:03 maybe?

Comment: There is no reason for B to take 45 minutes in one transaction. Deletes can be done in a loop of smaller size in transactions of less than 30 seconds. Solves the timeout problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transactions don't have priority. Deadlock victims are chosen by the database, most commonly using things like "work required to roll it back". One way of avoiding a deadlock is to ensure that you block rather than deadlock, by accessing tables in the same order, and by taking locks at the eventual level (for example, taking an `UPDLOCK` when reading the data, to avoid two queries getting read locks, then one trying to escalate to a write lock). Ultimately, though, this is a tricky area - and something that takes 45M to complete (please tell me that isn't a single transaction!) is always going to cause problems.

Comment: I've edited my post and yes it's not a single transaction. I found out how to set deadlock priority via TSQL but of course that just helps to set which of both processes should fail. Mabye I should go with my first idea of supress start of A when B is ready to run.

Answer (score 1):

Rework process B to not delete it all at once but in smaller batches that never take more than 1 minute. Run those in a loop until all to be deleted is done.

Comment: I've edited my post. I'm already using one transaction per row, not one for all.

Comment: 30 seconds for one row? THat is insane, even with 10 x2gb blob (which would be reclaimed outside the transaction). I Would start debugging that. How overloaded is your server? What are the specs? Please udpate the qhestion... I see a serious issue here. A row cascaging to 100 other rows with 100 x 100mb should delete in less than 5 seconds.

Comment: I am not an expert on this and it was just a suggested value so lets say it runs the 2-5 secs like you said. It seems that's still enough time to get in conflict with another (inserting) transaction when both try to edit the table the same time.